# Socket.io is sending an array of characters instead of my string

Tags: node.js, socket.io

From the server to the client.

I've looked at the chat example and I can't tell what I'm doing differently that would affect that.  What would cause this behavior?

Comment: Are you sure? Sometimes you will find that a `string` gets represented as an array of characters. For example you can for loop over it. And I've also found debuggers sometimes show an array of characters instead of a string. This might not be a problem with socketio but instead with your analysis tool.

Comment: I've tried stepping through the javascript in the Chrome debugger in both the chat example and my code.  I see an array of chars for my code and a string for the chat example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I was sending it an array of chars.  My bad.